# Loop Through TabItem CheckBoxes

Tags: c#, wpf, checkbox

I have a group of 50 `CheckBoxes` that are placed inside a `TabItem`. On a button click, I need to loop through the `CheckBoxes` and based upon whether the `CheckBox.Ischecked` is `true` or `false`, it's relevant variable will be set to a 0 or a 1.

Here is some code I've begun with to try and get a start;

```
private void ApplyPrivilegeUpdateClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var newPrivilegeModel = new EmployeePrivilegeModel();
    int i = 0;
    foreach (CheckBox c in companiesTabItem)
    {
        if (c.IsChecked == true)
        {
            newPrivilegeModel.Priv1 = 1;
        }
        i++;
    }
}
```

`newPrivlegeModel.Priv1` - This goes up to `Priv50`, so `Priv1, Priv2, Priv3` etc etc. What I really don't want to have to do is do an `If` loop for all 50 `CheckBoxes` and set their relevant `Priv`.

I have two problems, how do I loop through all the 50 `CheckBoxes` in the `TabItem`? And how can I code the `newPrivlegeModel.Priv1` so that they are all automatically updated? For example, `newPrivlegeModel.Priv + i` does not work so how do I get round this?

Comment: You can address this exact problem by leveraging WPF's powerful binding system: bind each checkbox's IsChecked property to its appropriate EmployeePrivilegeModel property. A converter can be used to translate between booleans and integers. The MVVM pattern is the orthodox approach to doing this in WPF.

Comment: You should be using collection and binding

Comment: I have started using collections and binding elsewhere, the only issue there is that there are 5 `TabItems` each with 50 `CheckBoxes`, so I'd need 250 binding elements instead of 50.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you use `Dictionary` instead `ofEmployeePrivilegeModel`´?

I have a group of 50 CheckBoxes that are placed inside a TabItem. On a button click, I need to loop through the CheckBoxes and based upon whether the CheckBox.Ischecked is true or false, it's relevant variable will be set to a 0 or a 1.

Here is some code I've begun with to try and get a start;

```
private void ApplyPrivilegeUpdateClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var newPrivilegeModel = new Dictionary<string,int>();
    int i = 0;
    foreach (CheckBox c in companiesTabItem)
    {
        if (c.IsChecked == true)
        {
            if(newPrivilegeModel.ContainstKey("Priv"+(i + 1).ToString())){
              newPrivilegeModel["Priv"+(i + 1).ToString()]=1;
            }
            else
            {
              newPrivilegeModel.Add("Priv"+(i + 1).ToString(),1);
            }
        }
        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: The main reason I'm trying to use `EmployeePrivilegeModel` is because I need to update them in my `MySQL` `Database`.

Comment: Also this does not solve how I would loop through all `CheckBoxes` on the `TabItem` in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Add either an array or list to the EmployeePrivilegeModel class to hold all the values.

```
var newPrivilegeModel = new EmployeePrivilegeModel();
newPrivilegeModel.PrivList = new List<bool>();
foreach (CheckBox c in companiesTabItem)
{
    if (c.IsChecked == true)
    {
        newPrivilegeModel.PrivList.Add(1);
    }
    else
    {
        newPrivilegeModel.PrivList.Add(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: I assume I would then loop through the `PrivList` to decide on the value needed to add to `MySQL`?

Comment: Yes.  PrivList<0> would map to your first column in your database, PrivList<1> to the second column, etc.

Comment: Ok thanks. Do you also know how to loop through all the `CheckBoxes` on a `TabItem`? Doing only this does not work at the moment: `foreach (CheckBox c in companiesTabItem)`